# O WebBrowser está funcinando no IISExpress do Visual Studio, mas não está funcionando no ISS do Windows

Tags: c#, navegador-de-internet, iis

O WebBrowser está funcinando no IISExpress do Visual Studio, mas não está funcionando no ISS do Windows.

Eu executo este código após criar o *Thread* `SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)`

```
try
{
    //BrowserValidate.FixBrowserVersion();
    webBet = new WebBrowser();
    webBet.DocumentCompleted += webBet_DocumentCompleted;
    webBet.Navigate("https://www.site.com");

    Application.Run();
}
catch (Exception)
{
}
```

Comment: E qual é o erro apresentado?

Comment: Então @LeandroAngelo ele não apresenta erro, apenas não executa mais nada apos o Application.Run(); na teoria deveira chamar o meu método do DocumentCompleted, não chega nem a cair no método.

desde já obrigado pela ajuda.